# Php 7.4.5 strict types when extending

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-7, php-7.4

On 2 development environments  my laravel installation behaves differently which is super weird.
(*both php7.4.5 a linux-php-fpm and macos-built-in php server*)

The default middleware `TrimStrings` defines `$except`

```
protected array $except = [ ...
```

Which is fine for my local branch (ran within php built-in server), if I remove the type 'array' - it breaks:

```
Type of App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::$except must be array (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings)
```

But on the server (php-fpm same version / linux instead of Mac) one with fpm it's exactly the opposite:

If there is type declaration it breaks.

```
Type of App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::$except must not be defined (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings)
```

It's a default laravel installation, any ideas why that differs so much ?

Comment: Apparently theres something with the laravel version went to upgrade v7.7.1 => v7.9.2 and now it synced the error with my server version.. which means it doesn't want me to define the type..

Comment: In laravel 7.9.2 `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` they removed the type ..